# UIView automatically up - When push from a TabbarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, chat, quickblox

Hi I am push a ViewController (CustomViewContoller - QuickBlox) from a tabbar.
Please look at the screenshot below.
a view is litle bit up from the tabbar top.

But, When I use the same scenario without tabbar it is looking fine.

Please let me know what is the issue around there.

[image]

Comment: Try this, Goto CustomViewContoller in storyboard. Select Attributes Inspector and unmark `Adjust Scroll View Insets`

Comment: I'll answer the same if it works :D

Comment: @CoderFrom94: not solved . still have the problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your view's frame in your debugger, try to set the frame by code.
2. If you're using auto-layout, double check your view's constraints.
3. If you're using storyboard, there may have a little bug if you unselected `transparent`, so try to set your `tabbar` `transparent` by code rather than set it in storyboard.

It will be easier to find the problem if you can post your method which implements the `tabbar`.

Answer (score 0):

Select the ViewController you worked on.

Go to the Attribute Inspector.

In Attribute Inspector View Controller section

- Unmark Adjust Scroll View Insets (layout)
- Checkmark Hide Bottom Bar on Push (layout)
- Checkmark Under Opaque Bars (Extend Edges)

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: still have the problem